# "out of memory" issue with PETsc in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, openmdao, petsc

I am running an OpenMDAO code that uses 2 parallel groups. I have installed PETSc4py and mpi4py inside a virtual python environment. I am getting the following error while running my code. The error reads as follows: "Out of memory. Allocated: 0, Used by process: 236814336"
Here is the full error message:

```
File "PETSc/Scatter.pyx", line 42, in petsc4py.PETSc.Scatter.create
petsc4py.PETSc.Error: error code 55
[1] VecScatterCreate() line 282 in /tmp/pycharm-packaging/petsc/src/vec/vscat/interface/vscreate.c
[1] VecScatterSetUp() line 211 in /tmp/pycharm-packaging/petsc/src/vec/vscat/interface/vscatfce.c
[1] VecScatterSetUp_MPI1() line 2543 in /tmp/pycharm-packaging/petsc/src/vec/vscat/impls/mpi1/vpscat_mpi1.c
[1] VecScatterSetUp_vectype_private() line 865 in /tmp/pycharm-packaging/petsc/src/vec/vscat/impls/vscat.c
[1] VecScatterCreate_PtoP() line 746 in /tmp/pycharm-packaging/petsc/src/vec/vscat/impls/vscat.c
[1] VecScatterCreateLocal_PtoP_MPI1() line 2436 in /tmp/pycharm-packaging/petsc/src/vec/vscat/impls/mpi1/vpscat_mpi1.c
[1] PetscMallocA() line 390 in /tmp/pycharm-packaging/petsc/src/sys/memory/mal.c
[1] VecScatterCreateLocal_PtoP_MPI1() line 2436 in /tmp/pycharm-packaging/petsc/src/vec/vscat/impls/mpi1/vpscat_mpi1.c
[1] Out of memory. Allocated: 0, Used by process: 237649920
[1] Memory requested 18446744062962991104
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[43240,1],1]
  Exit code:    1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I call the process with the following code:

```
mpirun -np 2 python ./parallel_processing.py
```

Here is the code for IDF optimization:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from openmdao.api import Problem, ScipyOptimizeDriver, SqliteRecorder
import time
import random
from openmdao.recorders.case_reader import CaseReader

from ssbj_vanaret_mda import SsbjMda
from ssbj_vanaret_idf2_mda import SsbjIdf2Mda


def idf_run2(nx, ny):

    # make a counter for discipline calls
    [str_count, aer_count, pro_count] = np.zeros(3)
    a = ["str_count.p", "aer_count.p", "pro_count.p"]
    for i in a:
        with open(i, "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(0, f)

    # Initialize an MDA to generate the starting point for IDF
    prob_init = Problem()  # initialize the optimization problem
    prob_init.model = SsbjMda(nx_input=nx)  # create the MDA

    # Design variables
    prob_init.model.add_design_var('z',  lower=np.zeros(nx), upper=np.ones(nx))
    prob_init.model.add_design_var('x1', lower=np.zeros(nx), upper=np.ones(nx))
    prob_init.model.add_design_var('x2', lower=np.zeros(nx), upper=np.ones(nx))
    prob_init.model.add_design_var('x3', lower=np.zeros(nx), upper=np.ones(nx))

    # Objective function
    prob_init.model.add_objective('range')

    # Constraints
    for i in range(nx):
        prob_init.model.add_constraint('con_g1' + str(i + 1), upper=0)
        prob_init.model.add_constraint('con_g2' + str(i + 1), upper=0)
        prob_init.model.add_constraint('con_g3' + str(i + 1), upper=0)

    prob_init.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver(optimizer='SLSQP')
    prob_init.driver.options['maxiter'] = 0

    prob_init.setup(mode='fwd')
    prob_init.set_solver_print(1)
    prob_init.run_driver()
    prob_init.cleanup()
    y12_initial = prob_init['y12']
    y23_initial = prob_init['y23']
    y32_initial = prob_init['y32']
    y21_initial = prob_init['y21']
    y31_initial = prob_init['y31']

    # : initialize MDA for IDF
    prob = Problem()
    prob.model = SsbjIdf2Mda(nx, ny, y12_initial, y23_initial, y32_initial, y21_initial, y31_initial)
    # create the MDA
    # Design variables
    prob.model.add_design_var('z', lower=np.zeros(nx), upper=np.ones(nx))  # shared variables
    prob.model.add_design_var('x1', lower=np.zeros(nx), upper=np.ones(nx))  # local variable for structural discipline
    prob.model.add_design_var('x2', lower=np.zeros(nx), upper=np.ones(nx))  # local variable for aerodynamic discipline
    prob.model.add_design_var('x3', lower=np.zeros(nx), upper=np.ones(nx))  # local variable for propulsion discipline

    # # coupling variables
    prob.model.add_design_var('y31')
    prob.model.add_design_var('y12')
    prob.model.add_design_var('y32')
    prob.model.add_design_var('y23')
    prob.model.add_design_var('y21')

    # Objective function
    prob.model.add_objective('obj')

    # Constraints
    for i in range(nx):
        prob.model.add_constraint('con_g1' + str(i + 1), upper=0)
        prob.model.add_constraint('con_g2' + str(i + 1), upper=0)
        prob.model.add_constraint('con_g3' + str(i + 1), upper=0)

    epsilon = 1e-9
    # Coupling constraints
    for i in range(ny):
        prob.model.add_constraint('con_y12' + str(i + 1), upper=epsilon)
        prob.model.add_constraint('con_y21' + str(i + 1), upper=epsilon)
        prob.model.add_constraint('con_y23' + str(i + 1), upper=epsilon)
        prob.model.add_constraint('con_y32' + str(i + 1), upper=epsilon)
        prob.model.add_constraint('con_y31' + str(i + 1), upper=epsilon)

    # Optimizer options
    prob.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver()
    prob.set_solver_print(2)
    prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
    for tol in [1e-3]:
        prob.driver.options['maxiter'] = random.randint(40, 50)
        prob.driver.options['tol'] = tol
        prob.driver.add_recorder(SqliteRecorder("cases_idf.sql"))
        # Run optimization
        start_time = time.time()
        prob.setup(mode='fwd')

        # view_model(prob, outfile='n2_mdfgs.html', show_browser=True)
        prob.run_driver()
        prob.run_model()
        # prob.check_partials()
        prob.cleanup()
        end_time = time.time()
        total_time = end_time - start_time
        if prob.driver.options['tol'] == 1e-6:
            iters = len(CaseReader('cases_idf.sql').get_cases())
            cr = CaseReader('cases_idf.sql')
            case_ids = cr.get_cases()
            obj_list = ['obj']
            z = []
            [z.append(case.get_objectives(case)[obj_list[0]]) for case in case_ids]
            with open("df_idf.p", "rb") as f:
                df_idf = pickle.load(f).append(pd.DataFrame({'total iterations[IDF]': [iters],
                                                             'total time[IDF]': [total_time],
                                                             'final_objective[IDF]': z[-1]}))
            with open("df_idf.p", "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(df_idf, f)

        elif prob.driver.options['tol'] == 1e-3:
            iters = len(CaseReader('cases_idf.sql').get_cases())
            cr = CaseReader('cases_idf.sql')
            case_ids = cr.get_cases()
            obj_list = ['obj']
            z = []
            a = ["str_count.p", "aer_count.p", "pro_count.p"]
            k = []
            for i in a:
                with open(i, "rb") as f:
                    k.append(pickle.load(f))
            [z.append(case.get_objectives(case)[obj_list[0]]) for case in case_ids]
            with open("df_idf_tol.p", "rb") as f:
                df_idf = pickle.load(f).append(pd.DataFrame({'10.total iterations[IDF_tol]': [iters],
                                                            '11.total time[IDF_tol]': [total_time],
                                                             '12.final_objective[IDF_tol]': z[-1],
                                                             '13.str_count[IDF_tol]': k[0],
                                                             '14.aer_count[IDF_tol]': k[1],
                                                             '15.pro_count[IDF_tol]': k[2]
                                                             }))
            with open("df_idf_tol.p", "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(df_idf, f)
```

The MDA for IDF optimization goes here:

```
from openmdao.api import Group
import numpy as np
from openmdao.api import IndepVarComp, ExecComp, ParallelGroup
from ssbj_vanaret_discipline import StructureDisc
from ssbj_vanaret_discipline import AerodynamicsDisc
from ssbj_vanaret_discipline import PropulsionDisc
from ssbj_vanaret_discipline import PerformanceDisc


class SsbjIdf2Mda(Group):

    """
    Analysis for IDF formulation where couplings are managed as additional constraints
    on input/output variables of related disciplines.
    """
    def __init__(self, nx_input, ny_input, y12_initial, y23_initial, y32_initial, y21_initial, y31_initial):
        super(SsbjIdf2Mda, self).__init__()
        self.nx = nx_input
        self.ny = ny_input
        self.y12 = y12_initial
        self.y23 = y23_initial
        self.y32 = y32_initial
        self.y31 = y31_initial
        self.y21 = y21_initial

    def setup(self):
        # Design variables
        self.add_subsystem('z_ini',  IndepVarComp('z',  .5 * np.ones(self.nx)), promotes=['*'])
        self.add_subsystem('x1_ini', IndepVarComp('x1', .5 * np.ones(self.nx)), promotes=['*'])
        self.add_subsystem('x2_ini', IndepVarComp('x2', .5 * np.ones(self.nx)), promotes=['*'])
        self.add_subsystem('x3_ini', IndepVarComp('x3', .5 * np.ones(self.nx)), promotes=['*'])

        # Couplings
        self.add_subsystem('y31_ini', IndepVarComp('y31', self.y31), promotes=['*'])
        self.add_subsystem('y12_ini', IndepVarComp('y12', self.y12), promotes=['*'])
        self.add_subsystem('y32_ini', IndepVarComp('y32', self.y32), promotes=['*'])
        self.add_subsystem('y23_ini', IndepVarComp('y23', self.y23), promotes=['*'])
        self.add_subsystem('y21_ini', IndepVarComp('y21', self.y21), promotes=['*'])

        # Disciplines

        parallel = self.add_subsystem('parallel', ParallelGroup())
        parallel.add_subsystem('Structure', StructureDisc())
        parallel.add_subsystem('Aerodynamics', AerodynamicsDisc())
        self.add_subsystem('Propulsion', PropulsionDisc())
        self.add_subsystem('Performance', PerformanceDisc())

        # Shared variables z
        self.connect('z', 'parallel.Structure.z')
        self.connect('z', 'parallel.Aerodynamics.z')
        self.connect('z', 'Propulsion.z')
        self.connect('z', 'Performance.z')

        # Local variables
        self.connect('x1', 'parallel.Structure.x1')
        self.connect('x2', 'parallel.Aerodynamics.x2')
        self.connect('x3', 'Propulsion.x3')
        self.connect('x1', 'Performance.x1')
        self.connect('x2', 'Performance.x2')
        self.connect('x3', 'Performance.x3')

        # Coupling variables
        self.connect('y21', 'parallel.Structure.y21')
        self.connect('y31', 'parallel.Structure.y31')
        self.connect('y32', 'parallel.Aerodynamics.y32')
        self.connect('y12', 'parallel.Aerodynamics.y12')
        self.connect('y23', 'Propulsion.y23')

        # Objective function
        self.add_subsystem('Obj', ExecComp('obj=range'), promotes=['obj'])

        # Connections
        self.connect('Performance.range', 'Obj.range')
        # self.connect('Propulsion.y34', 'Performance.y34')
        # self.connect('Aerodynamics.y24', 'Performance.y24')
        # self.connect('Structure.y14', 'Performance.y14')
        self.connect('parallel.Aerodynamics.y21', 'Performance.y21')
        self.connect('Propulsion.y31', 'Performance.y31')
        self.connect('Propulsion.y32', 'Performance.y32')
        self.connect('parallel.Structure.y12', 'Performance.y12')
        self.connect('parallel.Aerodynamics.y23', 'Performance.y23')

        # Coupling constraints
        for i in range(self.ny):
            self.add_subsystem('con_Y12' + str(i + 1),
                               ExecComp('con_y12' + str(i + 1) + '=(y12[' + str(i) + '] - y12k[' + str(i) + ']) ** 2',
                                        y12=self.y12,
                                        y12k=self.y12
                                        ),
                               promotes=['con_y12' + str(i + 1)])
            self.connect('parallel.Structure.y12', 'con_Y12' + str(i + 1) + '.y12')
            self.connect('y12', 'con_Y12' + str(i + 1) + '.y12k')

        for i in range(self.ny):
            self.add_subsystem('con_Y21' + str(i + 1),
                               ExecComp('con_y21' + str(i + 1) + '=(y21[' + str(i) + '] - y21k[' + str(i) + ']) ** 2',
                                        y21=self.y21,
                                        y21k=self.y21
                                        ),
                               promotes=['con_y21' + str(i + 1)])
            self.connect('parallel.Aerodynamics.y21', 'con_Y21' + str(i + 1) + '.y21')
            self.connect('y21', 'con_Y21' + str(i + 1) + '.y21k')

        for i in range(self.ny):
            self.add_subsystem('con_Y32' + str(i + 1),
                               ExecComp('con_y32' + str(i + 1) + '=(y32[' + str(i) + '] - y32k[' + str(i) + ']) ** 2',
                                        y32=self.y32,
                                        y32k=self.y32
                                        ),
                               promotes=['con_y32' + str(i + 1)])
            self.connect('Propulsion.y32', 'con_Y32' + str(i + 1) + '.y32')
            self.connect('y32', 'con_Y32' + str(i + 1) + '.y32k')

        for i in range(self.ny):
            self.add_subsystem('con_Y23' + str(i + 1),
                               ExecComp('con_y23' + str(i + 1) + '=(y23[' + str(i) + '] - y23k[' + str(i) + ']) ** 2',
                                        y23=self.y23,
                                        y23k=self.y23
                                        ),
                               promotes=['con_y23' + str(i + 1)])
            self.connect('parallel.Aerodynamics.y23', 'con_Y23' + str(i + 1) + '.y23')
            self.connect('y23', 'con_Y23' + str(i + 1) + '.y23k')

        for i in range(self.ny):
            self.add_subsystem('con_Y31' + str(i + 1),
                               ExecComp('con_y31' + str(i + 1) + '=(y31[' + str(i) + '] - y31k[' + str(i) + ']) ** 2',
                                        y31=self.y31,
                                        y31k=self.y31
                                        ),
                               promotes=['con_y31' + str(i + 1)])
            self.connect('Propulsion.y31', 'con_Y31' + str(i + 1) + '.y31')
            self.connect('y31', 'con_Y31' + str(i + 1) + '.y31k')

        # Local constraints
        for i in range(self.nx):
            self.add_subsystem('con_G1' + str(i + 1),
                               ExecComp('con_g1' + str(i + 1) + '=g1[' + str(i) + ']', g1=np.zeros(self.nx)),
                               promotes=['con_g1' + str(i + 1)])
            self.connect('parallel.Structure.g1', 'con_G1' + str(i + 1) + '.g1')

        for i in range(self.nx):
            self.add_subsystem('con_G2' + str(i + 1),
                               ExecComp('con_g2' + str(i + 1) + '=g2[' + str(i) + ']', g2=np.zeros(self.nx)),
                               promotes=['con_g2' + str(i + 1)])
            self.connect('parallel.Aerodynamics.g2', 'con_G2' + str(i + 1) + '.g2')

        for i in range(self.nx):
            self.add_subsystem('con_G3' + str(i + 1),
                               ExecComp('con_g3' + str(i + 1) + '=g3[' + str(i) + ']', g3=np.zeros(self.nx)),
                               promotes=['con_g3' + str(i + 1)])
            self.connect('Propulsion.g3', 'con_G3' + str(i + 1) + '.g3')
```

Comment: we'll need more information than this. Can you replicate the problem with a simple example script you can post?

Comment: I have attached the part of the IDf code that shows the 2 groups.
I am using "prob.setup(check=False, mode='fwd')
" as given in the parallel group example in the manual

Comment: I'm not clicking on that. Judging by the error message, the error has happened previously. You are already out of memory due to some previous problem. Then you try to do something else, and it all falls apart. But we expect a self-contained demonstration of the problem because ... if you follow the guidelines you will find the error on your own or make it possible for someone to help, but otherwise we have bug reports like "something's wrong," and there's no possible way to address it. (alternatively, this allocation is requesting more memory than you have due to a bug, like -1 unsigned)

Comment: I am not sure if I could put it in a more structured way so i put a snapshot of the error itself. I changed the structure a little bit now but I am not sure which part of the error is relevant here. But thanks for your help anyways

Comment: can you post the actual run script that you call? That way we can run it ourselves and see the error.